# How to input multiple variables on one line

Tags: python, input

I'm attempting to solve the Kattis Problem: Convex Polygon Area. I have a solution that basically gets the correct answers. However, there are still a few tweaks that need to be made in order for it to be acceptable by Kattis' standards. Here is my code:

```
class GetData:
    def coords() -> tuple[int, int]:
        x, y = map(int, input().split())
        return x, y

    def polygons(n) -> list:
        data = []
        ## Collect data for 'n' polygons
        for i in range(n):
            coord_list = []
            ## number of points for the current polygon
            m = int(input())
            ## Collect data for 'm' pairs of coordinates for the current polygon
            for j in range(m):
                x, y = GetData.coords()
                coord_list.append((x, y))
                if j == (m-1):  # all coordinate points have been defined
                    area = Area.calculate(coord_list)
                    data.append(area)
        return data
```

The main issue with this code is that it cannot take input in the way that Kattis wants it to, which involves inputting all coordinate points for a given polygon on one line. For example, here is the sample input that Kattis gives:

```
2
3 1 1 2 1 2 2
4 0 0 10 0 13 5 10 8
```

Instead, I have to input each of the coordinate pairs on a separate line:

```
2
3
1 1
2 1
2 2
4
0 0
10 0
13 5
10 8
```

If I try to input the way Kattis does it, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/asaylor/Projects/OOP-ajsaylor/assignments/A2-OOD/convex-polygon-area.py", line 68, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/asaylor/Projects/OOP-ajsaylor/assignments/A2-OOD/convex-polygon-area.py", line 61, in main
    data = GetData.polygons(n)
  File "/home/asaylor/Projects/OOP-ajsaylor/assignments/A2-OOD/convex-polygon-area.py", line 18, in polygons
    m = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3 1 1 2 1 2 2'
```

Here's my current outlook on the problem: I know how I can get the input to work on one line if I was coding a set amount of coordinate points into the program- Let's say I wanted the program to always take 3 pairs of coordinates. In that case, I would do something like `x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = map(int, input().split())`. However, I'm having the user decide the amount of coordinate points that the program defines, meaning that the program does not know how many values it needs to define, and as a result, I cannot write code like the example I gave.

Because of this, I was wondering if anyone had ideas as to what I need to do to get my program to accept input in the same way as Kattis does?

Comment: You have something already: `map(int, input().split())` which you can use again for this.

Comment: Your question contains a lot of unnecessary information. You should distill it down to the actual problem: You want to parse the input when it doesn't contain line breaks. You already know how to separate two numbers, why not apply the same thing to more than two?

Comment: The program allows for an indefinite amount of coordinate points to be defined for a given polygon. Because of this, the user inputs an integer 'm' to specify how many sides the polygon has, and a for-loop is executed to define 'm' pairs of coordinates. With this in mind, how would I use split() when the program doesn't know how many times it would have to be used?

Comment: @Austin Why would you have to split more than once? You can write code to break a list into chunks.

Comment: I'm new to python- so I may be missing something, but as far as I know I can break a list into chunks, after the list has been created. Because I'm creating lists of coordinates, I can input 2 variables per line: an x and y value, representing one coordinate point. However, I need to be able to input the entire list of coordinates on one line: so something like "4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8". In the example input I gave in the previous sentence, '4' should tell the program that there are 4 coordinate points. Then, "1 2" represents the first coordinate point, "3 4" represents the 2nd, etc.

Comment: The only code I took from online was the shoelace formula- specifically, the code in the "for s in range(len(coord_list)): " loop on line 40. The rest was completely written by me.

Comment: Here's my current outlook on the problem: I know how I can do that if I was coding a set amount of coordinate points into the program- Let's say I wanted the program to always take 3 pairs of coordinates. In that case, I would do something like "x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = map(int, input().split())". However, I'm having the user decide the amount of coordinate points that the program defines, meaning that the program does not know how many values it needs to define, and as a result, I cannot write code like the example I gave.

Comment: @Austin `split()` will divide a string into a list of `n` items, if there are `n` space separated alphanumeric inputs in the string.. meaning, for every whitespace, `split()` will divide the string into one more element.. 8 space separated integers in a string will be divided into a list of 8 strings, each of them which u can convert to int using int() function

Comment: @a_n Too many people using ChatGPT junk. Though I admit I had misjudged this, hadn't realized that most of their code is for input (should've been at most a handful of lines) and thought the algorithm was large.

Comment: @Austin Ah OK, it seems like you need to learn how to work with dynamically sized data (lists in this case). Please add the info from your most recent comment into the question, and while you're there, slim down the code to just what's relevant to the question (similar to what pho said); like for example, the area calculation isn't relevant.

Comment: @Kelly Oh oops, I was going to say "make sure it's reproducible, see [mre]", but then I was thinking MREs are more about debugging, not how-to's, so I reasoned myself out of it. Yeah, for the sake of example, I'd remove  `Area.calculate` *entirely* and instead do `data.append(coord_list)` (which, BTW, `data.append` should be outside the `j` loop; `if j == (m-1)` is entirely unnecessary and wouldn't work in the degenerate case of 0 points). I'd also remove the class.

Comment: @wjandrea Yeah, really should've just been about reading one polygon, returning a list of int-pairs. Nothing else. Though at this point that would make the answers weird/wasted.

Comment: `GetData` isn't a good class name. Classes are usually nouns, functions/methods are verbs. Consider something like `InputParser`.

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding of the input format of the problem you're trying to solve, number of polygons `n` is given on the first line. Then `n` lines follow, each of which have their first integer `m` as the number of points in the polygon, and `2*m` integers in the format `x1 y1 x2 y2 ... xm ym`.
Here's the link to the corresponding problem I found on Kattis - [Convex Polygon Area](https://open.kattis.com/contests/pyktb9/problems/convexpolygonarea)

#### The `str.split()` method in Python

In Python, the `split()` method, when used without any arguments, splits a string into a list of strings based on the whitespaces present in the string. For instance, using `split()` on a string like `'My name is alien.'` will split it into a list of 4 and return `['My', 'name', 'is', 'alien.']`.

---

So you can take one line of input, split the elements, and take pairs of elements from index `1` onwards of the list (you don't need the first element).
(We're using [list comprehensions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) in this code)

```py
def main() -> None:
    n: int = int(input())
    data = []
    
    for i in range(n):
        # Split the line into a list of a number of strings
        # Discard the first number as we don't need it
        line = input().split()[1:]
        
        x_coords = [int(x) for x in line[::2]] # alternative integers starting from index 0
        y_coords = [int(x) for x in line[1::2]] # alternative integers starting from index 1
        
        coord_list = list(zip(x_coords, y_coords))
        
        # --- Your code from here ---
        
        ## If all coordinate points have been defined, calculate the area
        area = Area.calculate(coord_list)

        ## Add the area of this polygon to the 'data' list
        data.append(area)

    Area.print(data)
```

---

You don't need the `GetData` class at all! And by the way, I hope you are aware of how classes work in Python. They require the first parameter in every method to be `self` (a variable pointing to its instance), unless you define it to be a static method, using the `@staticmethod` decorator. In this problem, you don't need classes at all!

Comment: Note about the final paragraph. Static class members don't use the `self` parameter. [Class (static) variables and methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68672/669576)

Comment: i didn't see a `@staticmethod` decorator anywhere in the OP's code hence i typed out that paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Split the line, discard the first element, map to ints, zip to pairs.

```
class GetData:
    def polygons(n) -> list:
        return [
            Area.calculate([*zip(ints, ints)])
            for _ in range(n)
            for ints in [map(int, input().split()[1:])]
        ]
```

Or more like your style, most code is yours, except my two lines `ints = ...` and `coord_list = ...`:

```
class GetData:
    def polygons(n) -> list:
        data = []
        for _ in range(n):
            ints = map(int, input().split()[1:])
            coord_list = list(zip(ints, ints))
            area = Area.calculate(coord_list)
            data.append(area)
        return data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take all the inputs into a list, then you don't exactly *need* `m`, but I'll use it as a sanity check that the input is the right size. Then you just need to pair up the x's and y's, which I'll do with [`itertools.batched`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.batched) (which could let you easily expand to n-dimensional points if needed).

```py
from itertools import batched

...

m, *raw_coords = map(int, input().split())
assert len(raw_coords) == 2*m
coords = list(batched(raw_coords, 2))

area = Area.calculate(coords)
...
```